# Identify Menu Bar App — Up Arrow Line Underneath

Tags: mojave, menu-bar

There is an up arrow with a line underneath it in my menu bar. Clicking, right clicking, and CMD + Click does nothing. Also cannot drag and remove. Thoughts? I've never seen this before.

Running Mojave 10.14.5

[image]

Comment: I cannot comment on the reason, but removal would be Cmd + drag. And more info generally appears when Option+ click is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the caps lock icon from an external keyboard.

Are you using an external keyboard, maybe along with Logitech software?